Android HCE service not being recognized
I'm having a problem creating a simple HCE app but when trying to execute all i get is responses 6F00, I imagine thats due to the service not beign registered as an HCE service but i cant seem to find the solution as to why...
(Notice i'm using a foreground service to test if resolves anything... so any problems there are unrelated)
Thanks!
dumpsys nfc
mState=on
mIsZeroClickRequested=false
mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED
mTechMask: default
mEnableLPD: true
mEnableReader: false
mEnableHostRouting: true
mEnableP2p: false
Registered HCE services for current user:
    ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.nearby.mediums.nearfieldcommunication.NfcAdvertisingService} (Description: Nearby)
    On Host Service
    Static AID groups:
        Category: other
            AID: F00000FE2C
    Dynamic AID groups:
    Settings Activity: null
    Routing Destination: host
    Service State: ENABLING

    ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.hce.service.TpHceService} (Description: Google Pay)
    On Host Service
    Static AID groups:
        Category: payment
            AID: 325041592E5359532E4444463031
    Dynamic AID groups:
    Settings Activity: null
    Routing Destination: host

    ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.pay.hce.service.PayHceService} (Description: Google Wallet)
    On Host Service
    Static AID groups:
    Dynamic AID groups:
        Category: other
            AID: 4F53452E5641532E3031
            AID: A000000476D0000111
    Settings Activity: null
    Routing Destination: host
    Service State: ENABLING

    ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.dck.service.DckNfcApduService} (Description: Android Digital Car Key)
    On Host Service
    Static AID groups:
        Category: other
            AID: A000000809434343444B467631
    Dynamic AID groups:
    Settings Activity: null
    Routing Destination: host
    Service State: ENABLING


apduservice.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false"
    android:description="@string/service_description">
    <aid-group android:category="other" android:description="@string/aid_group_description">
        <aid-filter android:name="00000000000000"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>

MyHostApduService
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyHostApduService";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel(); // Create the notification channel
        startForeground(1, createNotification()); // Start the service in foreground
        Log.d(TAG, "HostApduService created");
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Command APDU received: " + bytesToHex(commandApdu));
        if (commandApdu == null || commandApdu.length == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Command APDU is null or empty");
            return getUnknownCommandResponse();
        }

        // Handle your APDU commands here
        return hexStringToByteArray("9000"); // Success status word
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service deactivated with reason: " + reason);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            }
        }
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Host APDU Service")
                .setContentText("Service is running in foreground")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
    }

    private byte[] getUnknownCommandResponse() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received unknown command");
        return hexStringToByteArray("6F00"); // Unknown command response
    }
//...
}

Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CardEmulator">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CardEmulator">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyHostApduService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
</manifest>


I tested in 2 different devices, the contectless payment options are set not set to any specific service as default.
try executing the service in the foreground.

It might be because the AID value you used of "00000000000000" is Reserved for backward compatibility with ISO/IEC 7812-1 according to Section "8.2.1.2 Application identifier" of ISO IEC 7816-4
This might cause problems and is not the right value to use.
All unregistered AID's should begin with "F"
So try using the AID "F0000000000000" as the aid-filter value in apduservice.xml

I added this later thinking it might be a AID conflict, but changing the AID still got the same problem...
But thanks anyway!

It might be worth checking out https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid as this works.
